# Eliminar un registro mostrando confirmacion

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Que tal amigos tengo esta funcion en jQuery que elimina un registro de una dataTable, lo que necesito es que se muestre una confirmación al hacer clic en el boton eliminar de la tabla, para que aparezca si en realidad se desea borrar y otro boton de cancelar, este es mi codigo:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(resp){
            window.location.href = base_url + resp;
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Algo como esto]
Algo asi como este sweetalert:

Comment: Puedes usar if(confirm("Validar?")){//EJECUTO}

Comment: Si estás usando DataTables, este ejemplo te va a servir: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html

Comment: Pero no es nada mas de borrar la fila, necesitaria usar lo de arriba lo que tiene mi funcion @RubenHernandez como hago lo de confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca esta la solucion con SweetAlert espero que les sirva, a mi me sirvio de maravilla, gracias a los que mostraron interes en mi pregunta, saludos.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    swal({
            title:"Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?",
            text: "Esta operacion es irreversible",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(resp){
                        window.location.href = base_url + resp;
                    }
                });
                }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

[image: SweetAlert]

Comment: Genial @WilsonicX gracias por compartirlo ahora se ve mucho mejor :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar algo asi

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    if(confirm("Esta seguro de eliminar?")){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                window.location.href = base_url + resp;
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});   
</script>}
```

Saludos :)

Comment: En base a tu respuesta la adapte para que se pudiera utilizar con SweetAlert, te dejo arriba mi respuesta basandome en la tuya.